# npm doesnt build latest file

Tags: laravel, npm, vue.js, laravel-mix

Maybe I am doing it wrong. I have modified a .vue template in node_modules folder. Now when I run `npm run watch` or `npm run dev` it doesn't get reflected in UI.

I am using Laravel 5.6 with Laravel Mix
Any idea whats wrong ?

thanks

Chintan

Comment: Don't modify vendor files.

Comment: How are you using a .vue file in the node_modules folder?

Comment: `node_modules` are ignored in webpack, and if you are writing your own `.vue` components then, put them into `resources/assets/js/components`